# c++: передача внешних параметров при поиске значений в векторе (при определённом операторе <, >)

Tags: c++, c++11, поиск, stl, c++14

Подскажите, как более правильнее и элегантнее решить следующую задачу:

**исходные данные:**

у меня есть структура:

```
struct object_t
{
    int     m_id = -1;
    int     m_pos = -1;
};
```

есть вектор данных:

```
using data_t = std::vector<object_t>;
```

а также есть внешний словарь слов

```
using dictionary_t = std::vector<std::string>;
```

в указанной структуре `m_id` - номер слова в словаре, а `m_pos` - позиция символа

**задача:**

необходимо найти в указанном векторе данных `data_t` запись, для которой выполнялись бы условия:

1. это слово максимальной длины
2. иначе это слово с минимальным значением
   позиции `m_pos`
3. иначе это слово с минимальным значением символа по
   указанной позиции `m_pos`

**реализация:**

сейчас это у меня сделано в лоб:

```
data_t::const_iterator optimalData = mydata.cbegin();   

for (data_t::const_iterator localData = mydata.cbegin(); localData != mydata.cend(); localData++)
{
    if (mydictionary[localData->m_id].size() > mydictionary[optimalData->m_id].size())
        optimalData = localData;
    else if (mydictionary[localData->m_id].size() == mydictionary[optimalData->m_id].size())
    {
        if (localData->m_pos < optimalData->m_pos)
            optimalData = localData;
        else if ((localData->m_pos == optimalData->m_pos) && (mydictionary[localData->m_id][localData->m_pos] < mydictionary[optimalData->m_id][optimalData->m_pos]))
            optimalData = localData;
    }
}
```

но такой код не очень удобно читается и такую реализацию лучше спрятать поглубже, поэтому думал реализовать через переопределение оператора `>`, тогда бы код выглядел бы понятно и красиво, а его реализация сидела бы в структуре `object_t`, а не в основном коде, т.е. было бы так:

```
data_t::const_iterator optimalData = mydata.cbegin();   

for (data_t::const_iterator localData = mydata.cbegin(); localData != mydata.cend(); localData++)
{
    if (*localData > *optimalData)
        optimalData = localData;
}
```

или даже средствами STL (вроде там была возможность найти максимальное значение поэтому получилась бы вообще одна строчка кода)

**проблема**

проблема реализации лишь в том как красиво и корректно передать `mydictionary`, который необходим для выполнения операции сравнения

**вопрос**

подскажите пожалуйста как корректнее и элегантнее можно это сделать, вообще правильный ли подход с переносом операции сравнения (через переопределение оператора), может ли это отразиться на производительность (компиляторы вроде как умные, но мало ли что)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `std::max_element`. В качестве функции-компаратора используйте лямбду, map'у захватывайте по ссылке.

Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct object_t {
    int o_idx;  // index
    int o_pri;  // priority
};

bool operator<(const object_t& _l, const object_t& _r);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const object_t& _o);

int main() {
    std::vector<object_t> obj_list { { 0, 100 }, { 1, 101 }, { 2, 100 } };

    std::map<int, std::string> str_map = {
        { 0, "fooX" },
        { 1, "fooY" },
        { 2, "fooY" }
    };

    auto max_elm = 
        std::max_element(obj_list.cbegin(), obj_list.cend(), [&str_map](const auto& _l, const auto& _r) {
            return str_map[_l.o_idx] == str_map[_r.o_idx] ?
                _l < _r : str_map[_l.o_idx] < str_map[_r.o_idx];
    });

    if (obj_list.cend() != max_elm) {
        std::cout << *max_elm;
        std::cout << "str: " << str_map[max_elm->o_idx] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

bool operator<(const object_t& _l, const object_t& _r) {
    return _l.o_pri < _r.o_pri;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& _s, const object_t& _o) {
    return _s << "idx: " << _o.o_idx << " nice: " << _o.o_pri << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: но тут все таки все равно большой код и логика остается в основном коде, т.е. надобности в переопределении оператора практически нет, логика работы все равно сидит в лямбде :(

Comment: @Zhihar, когда у меня там один индекс - да, согласен с Вами.

Comment: @Zhihar, а почему у Вас строки в map'е сторятся, а объекты - в векторе, отдельно?

Comment: строки - вещь неизменная (словарь), поэтому я их загружаю из файла и храню в векторе, т.е. они уже отсортированы и т.д. и используются не очень активно (поиск и т.п.), поэтому вектор для них самый удобный и компактный контейнер

а данные, которые я обрабатываю (по которым и сделан вопрос) - они динамически создаются и активно используются. 

а `map` у меня вообще не используется - он избыточен (как мне кажется)

Comment: Специально по этой причине все стандартные алгоритмы предоставляют свои "предикатные" версии, т.е. версии, использующие предикат для сравнения, а не оператор `<`. Оператор `<` должен реализовывать какое-то единственное наиболее естественное "главное" сравнение. Делать такое сравнение зависимым от внешних факторов не кажется мне хорошей практикой.

Comment: @AnT, "Делать такое сравнение зависимым от внешних факторов не кажется мне хорошей практикой" - в таком ключе я не думал, согласен с Вами. Спасибо за комментарий!